# How to replace using REGEX in dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Does anyone know how to use regex to replace string in dreamweaver?

Basically I want to change

.htm?" to .htm?" rel="nofollow"

I can find the string I am looking for in dreamweaver no problem

```
\.htm\?(.*?)\"
```

The above code finds the above string perfectly. However I think I am maybe getting a little confused with the replace part.

If I use the code

```
.htm?(.*?)" rel="nofollow"
```

In the replace section it replaces with exactly that. Is there some way I can get it to keep my parameter string?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is a capturing group. Incidentally you already have one. Parentheses capture whatever was matched inside them. Since you only have one set of parentheses, the capturing group is indexed with number `1`.

Try this replacement string:

```
.htm?$1" rel="nofollow"
```

Alternative, `$0` corresponds to the full match. So you could as well replace this with

```
$0 rel="nofollow"
```

**EDIT:** I cannot find anyone using `$0` in Dreamweaver right now. If it does not work, capture your whole match:

```
(\.htm\?(.*?)\")
```

And replace it with

```
$1 rel="nofollow"
```

Comment: Yeah that works. Was litterally just about to post your first solution as found a handy tutorial here http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html. Thanks so much for reading and also the lightening quick answer!

Comment: this works like a charm, I have been looking for a solution for ages! Thanks!